# How does Ethereum's Makerdao Dai stablecoin differ from EOS's Equilibrium EOSDT stable coin?

Tags: contract-design, dai, eos, makerdao

What are the main differences from Ethereum's makerdao dai stablecoin to EOS's equilibrium EOSDT stablecoin? And are there other stablecoins like these two that are decentralized and issued via a smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of EOSDT/NUT is a little similar to Maker: It’s a decentralized collateral-backed stablecoin solution. The difference being that Equilibrium is built on EOS blockchain which differentiates us from Maker in the following aspects:

- Zero transaction fees, much faster transaction processing times, thus ability to scale much faster
- Rates are much faster than in Maker/Ethereum, making the system more responsive to external price changes.
- Partial collateral superfluidity where portions of Equilibrium collateral may be used for Block Producer voting or REX staking.
- Much better decentralized governance thanks to built-in EOS governance features.
- Built-in ability to leverage any DPoS architecture and provide a true cross-chain solution with DPoS consensus blockchains.